# ASP .NET Ajax UpdatePanel Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException

Tags: asp.net

I have searched, and searched, .. and searched. I have seen many posts here and on other forums regarding a similar issue. However, none of them seem to be helping. I have posted the relating asp and vb code below (please forgive me for the vb it wasn't my choice). If you look at the vb code you will notice that I am building a link "

"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details: Error parsing near '7.180/test/Members/Widget/bob'>leader de'."

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="searchBtn" EventName="Click" /></Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="focusTab" runat="server" Value="" />
            <div id="tabs" class="tabsContainer">
                <ul>
                    <li id="c2Link"><a href="#c2Tab">bill</a></li>
                    <li id="intelLink"><a href="#intelTab">bob</a></li>
                    <li id="manLink"><a href="#manTab">man</a></li>
                    <li id="firesLink"><a href="#firesTab">fire</a></li>
                    <li id="protLink"><a href="#protTab">joe</a></li>
                    <li id="sustLink"><a href="#sustTab">jill</a></li>
                </ul>                
                <div id="c2Tab" class="panel">
                    <asp:Label ID="c2Results" runat="server" Text="No results found in this category."></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="intelTab" class="panel">
                    <asp:Label ID="intelResults" runat="server" Text="No results found in this category."></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="manTab" class="panel">
                    <asp:Label ID="manResults" runat="server" Text="No results found in this category."></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="firesTab" class="panel">
                    <asp:Label ID="firesResults" runat="server" Text="No results found in this category."></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="protTab" class="panel">
                    <asp:Label ID="protResults" runat="server" Text="No results found in this category."></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div id="sustTab" class="panel">
                    <asp:Label ID="sustResults" runat="server" Text="No results found in this category."></asp:Label>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>

   <span class="kwSearchHdr">Search (seperate keywords w/comma)</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="kwSearchTxt" runat="server" CssClass="kwSearchBx"/>  

   <span class="dateHdr">From/To Date</span>           
   <asp:TextBox ID="fromDateTxt" runat="server" CssClass="fromDate"/>
   <asp:TextBox ID="toDateTxt" runat="server" CssClass="toDate"/>

   <asp:Button ID="searchBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="searchBtn"/>
```

VB Code: The returned string as appended to a one of the labels

```
Private Function buildResultStr(ByVal result As AdvisorInsightView) As String
    Dim resultsStr As String = ""
    Dim baseUrl As String = "./WidgetViewInsight.aspx?Insight={0}"
    Dim text As New TextFunctions
    Dim snippet As String = ""
    Dim member As New JCISFAMember(Convert.ToInt16(result.Author))

    resultsStr += "<p>- <a href='"
    'resultsStr += Page.ResolveUrl(String.Format(baseUrl, result.InsightID))
    resultsStr += "' style='font-size:11;' >"
    resultsStr += result.Subject & "</a>, "
    resultsStr += Convert.ToDateTime(result.PubDate).ToShortDateString() & ", "
    resultsStr += member.GetAuthorDetails() & "<br />"

    snippet = text.stripRichTextFormatting(result.Observation)

    If snippet.Length > MAX_SNIP_LEN Then
        snippet = snippet.Substring(0, MAX_SNIP_LEN) & "..."
    End If

    resultsStr += snippet & "<br />"
    resultsStr += "<b>Keywords: </b>"

    If result.Keywords.Equals("") Then
        resultsStr += "None.</p>"
    Else
        resultsStr += "<span class='keywords'>"
        Dim keywords As String() = Split(result.Keywords, ", ")
        Dim keywordStr As String = ""
        Dim charCount As Integer = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To keywords.Length - 1
            If charCount + keywords(i).Length >= 75 Then
                keywordStr += "..."
                Exit For
            End If
            Dim url As String = "bob" ' "./SearchResults.aspx?CategoryID=" & keywords(i)
            keywordStr += "<a href='" & url & "'>" & keywords(i) & "</a>"

            If i <> keywords.Length - 1 Then
                keywordStr += ", "
            End If
            charCount += keywords(i).Length
        Next

        resultsStr += keywordStr & "</span></p>"
    End If

    Return resultsStr
End Function
```

Comment: can you past the entire response (not just the exception) here? Try using fiddler or just plain old firebug.

Comment: Unfortunately that would be very difficult to do. I am working with sensitive information which would be displayed if I posted that. I am assuming that you are referring to the Ajax response.

Comment: That is what I meant. If the server sends the response OK but its the client side script that is throwing the exception then the best approach is to take the returned response HTML, dump it in a new HTML page in visual studio and try and reformat it. VS will tell you where the HTML is incorrect

Comment: There was <p> tags within <span> tags which I removed. Those were the only html errors VS found. After I removed those I still have the same problem.

Comment: Also something I forgot to mention. This problems is only happening on the production server. On the asp dev server I do not have this problem. I tried disabling output caching on the prod server with no success

Comment: If it's only happening on one server, I'd suspect a custom HttpModule that's transparently adding markup to the response.  Appending anything to the UpdatePanel response will break the client-side component's ability to parse the response.

Comment: The weird thing is that all I have to do is remove what I put in the href field of the anchor tag. Of course that is NOT a solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same error where the response is getting truncated, resulting in a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was inserting a partial url or path (e.g. href="./WebPage.aspx"). This causes the browser to fill in the rest of the url which is done by writing out to the response and therefore causes the issue here. I.E. in order to solve this problem I have to build a full uri to put in the href field on server side in order to stop and writes to the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short in the dark but I have had this problem with a custom control I was using. Try adding this to your code behind (form load) and see if this makes a difference

```
Page.Form.Method = "post";
        Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to help.